# Error Joining Tables in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, orm

Hello I am trying to join the `User` And `Candidate` table. I want column `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `phone` from `Candidate` table and join with `password` column of `User` table. I tried doing this but getting some sort of error. My code is given below:

```
CREATE TABLE `candidate` (`candidate_id` bigint(12) NOT NULL,`user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,`firstname` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`lastname` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`dob` date DEFAULT NULL,`gender` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,`phone` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`address_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,`profile_title` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`profile_summary` varchar(10000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`total_experience` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'year,month',`current_location` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`current_salary` double DEFAULT NULL,`expected_salary` double DEFAULT NULL,`status` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`percentage` int(45) DEFAULT NULL,`updated_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`noticeperiod` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,`martialstatus` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`currentoffer` double DEFAULT NULL,`idproof` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`industry` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`functionalarea` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`functionalrole` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`resign` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,`preferlocation` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`type` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`notice_period_update` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,`passport` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,`gross_salary` double DEFAULT NULL,`profile_type` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`rrm_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`candidate_id`), KEY `Candidate_Address_idx` (`address_id`),KEY `Can_user` (`user_id`),KEY `CandidateStatus_idx` (`status`),KEY `CandidatePercent_idx` (`percentage`), KEY `user_id_idx` (`rrm_user_id`),CONSTRAINT `Can_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,CONSTRAINT `Candidate_Address` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `address`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, CONSTRAINT `user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`rrm_user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

My User Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,`password` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`first_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`last_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`type` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`active` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,`deleted` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,`timezone` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`created_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,`updated_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`activationcode` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`secure_key` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`),UNIQUE KEY `username_UNIQUE` (`username`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1505 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

My Entity Class:

```
@Table(name = "CANDIDATE")public class SignUp {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private String candidate_id;
@Column
private String firstname;
@Column
private String lastname;
@Column
private String email;
@Column
private String phone;

public String getCandidate_id() {
    return candidate_id;
}

public void setCandidate_id(String candidate_id) {
    this.candidate_id = candidate_id;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id")
private Password password;

public Password getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(Password password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

For User Table:

```
@Table(name = "USER")public class Password { @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private String id;
@Column
private String password;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private SignUp signUp;

public SignUp getSignUp() {
    return signUp;
}

public void setSignUp(SignUp signUp) {
    this.signUp = signUp;
}
```

Error m getting is:

```
Hibernate: 
select
    password0_.id as id1_1_0_,
    password0_.password as password2_1_0_,
    password0_.user_id as user_id4_1_0_,
    signup1_.candidate_id as candidat1_0_1_,
    signup1_.email as email2_0_1_,
    signup1_.firstname as firstnam3_0_1_,
    signup1_.lastname as lastname4_0_1_,
    signup1_.phone as phone5_0_1_ 
from
    User password0_ 
left outer join
    CANDIDATE signup1_ 
        on password0_.user_id=signup1_.candidate_id 
where
    password0_.id=?
```

> Jun 01, 2017 4:48:45 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions WARN:
>   SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22 Jun 01, 2017 4:48:45 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions ERROR:
>   Unknown column 'password0_.user_id' in 'field list'

Comment: show us how do you assemble / call the query from java code

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get u Sir?

Comment: so when you call something like.. getCurrentSession().createQuery(QUERY).uniqueResult();. Im interested in that QUERY part

Comment: public List<SignUp> getSignUp(){
        Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from SignUp");
        List<SignUp> signUps =  query.list();
        session.close();
        return signUps;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mappings are fine, you just missed the `user_id` in the `CREATE TABLE user` statement as based on this mapping:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private SignUp signUp;
```

hibernate expects to make a join to the `CERTIFICATE` table through that column.

Also dont forget to add the foreign key statement in your DDL.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Jboss reverse engineering tool for hibernate to generate domain and  avoid such mistakes.It is very easy and you can create domains from database table within 5 minutes.